# Unable to Install keras/tensorflow in Rstudio

Tags: r, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

i am trying to execute the a sample programme to learn about Deep Learning RNN for Forecasting [Link for RNN Code for Forecasting](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/blog/time-series-forecasting-with-recurrent-neural-networks.html). i found this link for reference , In this is link when we try developing model i am getting an error.

[image]

I am clueless about the error , i have followed proper method for installation. i am working on time series data for forecasting.where i can predict one() to many(Output).

Comment: Have you run `install_keras()?`

Comment: Yes I did ,after executing library (keras) it is excepting also but after this code this is telling no keras found.